# How do I add common rows together?

Tags: r, plyr, tidyverse

This is an example of the data frame I am using

```
UserID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
Score <- c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,5,4,3,4,5,6,7)
Pass <- c("TRUE","FALSE","TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", 
"TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE")

a <- data.frame(UserID, Score, Pass)

a
```

The userid represents one person. That one person did three attempts. So number 1 has a score of 2,7, and 3. How do I sum the scores for each person so that instead of having three individual scores, I just have one.

Comment: have you tried anything? what was wrong with what you tried?

Comment: Yes, I have tried using the ddply function

Comment: I've tried this

Comment: ddply(a,.(userid),summarise) and I've also tried to pipe a %>% group_by(userid) %>% summarise (Score)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify what function you want to be summarized:

```
a %>%
 group_by(UserID) %>%
 summarize(sum(Score))
```